# Simple polynomial factorization

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $f(x) = x^3 + (a-5)$, where $a$ is some integer.

Find all the possibility of an integer $a$, such that $f(x)$ can be factorized.

I did one example: If $ a = 4$, then $f(x) = x^3 -1$ and $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$

I am looking for more such $‘a’$’s in order to factorize $ f(x)$

Could you help me to find all such $a$ as well as factors of $ f(x)?$

High regards to one and all.

Comment: What if a=5? Does $x^3$ itself count as a factorized or do there have to be non-zero factors?

Comment: @JB King! we want non-zero factors. SO we cannot take a = 5

Comment: What is a "nonzero factor"? $x$ is not zero, it is a polynomial of degree $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** We want $a-5$ to be a perfect cube, or the negative of a perfect cube. For $x^3-b^3=(x-b)(x^2+bx+b^2)$ and $x^3+b^3=(x+b)(x^2-bx+b^2)$.

**Remark:** These are the *only* situations in which the cubic factors over the integers, but it is not clear from the wording whether you are expected to prove that.

Comment: Why is $x^3 \pm b^3$ the only form factorizable for integers? Just wondering.

Comment: @taninamdar: The proof is too long for a comment. (i) if a monic (first coefficient $1$) cubic (or quadratic) factors over the integers then the cubic has an integer root. (ii) So if $x^3-c$ so factors the there is an integer $t$ such that $t^3=-c$. Alternate easier proof: (i) If a cubic factors, it has a rational root. (ii) If $c$ is not the cube of an integer, then $\sqrt[3]{c}$ is irrational. The easiest proof of (ii) uses the prime factorization of $c$.